# MOSFER Vg greater than Vd

Tags: mosfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkc6YZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will I cause any problems since Vg (4V) is greater than Vd (3.3V)?

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as Vg-s (gate-source) stays within the maximum allowed specified in the datasheet you're good.